# OpenTok - Publish non-camera video stream?

Tags: javascript, video, camera, opentok

Using OpenTok is there a way publish a video stream whose source is not a camera? That is, I would like to publish a video which is either pre-recorded or a video being generated by a source other than a camera. Any suggestions on how this can be done? Thank you much!

(Just as a quick reasoning for this, our system uses OpenTok using the normal approach, but we want to run tests with non-camera generated video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenTok, or any other framework, doesn't get the video stream directly from the camera. It asks the browser to redirect the camera feed. So you would have to trick the browser into providing a video file instead.

The easiest way to do this is to install a virtual webcam software. There are many options for that but I usually go with [splitcam](http://splitcamera.com/), mainly because it's free.